# my project is running but I get build error what could be the reason ? (Nextjs v 13)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Generating static pages (2/4)TypeError: fetch failed 
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11) 
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) 
at async getData (D:\dev-js\smweb-next.next\server\chunks\512.js:431:17)

my data fetch

```
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/product',{cache:"no-store"}); //{ next: { revalidate: 10 } }
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }

    return res.json();
  }

export const dataPromise = getData()
```

*Error occurred prerendering page "/".
TypeError: fetch failed 
*Error occurred prerendering page "/auth/signin". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

folder type

-app 
---auth 
-----signin 
-------page.tsx 
-pages 
---api 
-----auth 
-------[...nextauth].ts

```
[...nextauth].ts

 pages: {
    // custom page
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
```

> Build error occurred
> Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /auth/signin/page: /auth/signin
>
> what's the problem while building in NEXTJs v 13 ?